# Outer function on arrays fresulting rom Vectorize function

Tags: r, vectorization

I am Vectorizing a two parameters function and the result is a 3d array. To get this output I use outer function but I keep getting an error message (even when I cbind the Vectorized function).

I tried cbind as seen in other problems with similar error code.

```
n=20
mc=10
q=3

x=matrix(0,ncol=mc, nrow=n)
for (j in 1:mc){
x[,j]=arima.sim(n = n   , list(ar = .5))
}

gamhat=function(h1,h2){(1/n)*colSums((x[-c((n-(h1+h2)+1):n),]- 
colMeans(x))*(x[-c(1:h1,(n-h2+1):n),]-colMeans(x))*(x[-c(1:(h1+h2)),]- 
colMeans(x)))
}
covmat=outer(1:q,1:q,Vectorize(gamhat))
```

Expecting an array of 20*10*3 (as n x mc x q).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` to `Vectorize`,

```
 covmat=outer(1:q,1:q,Vectorize(gamhat, SIMPLIFY = F))
```

It might not be exactly what you were expecting since it will be a 3x3 of lists of numeric vectors, but that is what you are asking for in the first two arguments of outer.